# AirPrint in photos app

Tags: iphone, airprint

I just tried printing a photo and it cuts off the sides. It's a piece of yet so it's quite important to not cut off the sides. Is there a way to set which part of the photo prints? I ended up taking a screenshot ofthe photo when the UI hid which reduced the quality severely and printed a huge black border around wasting a lot of ink. So is there any way to access printer settings as is traditional on the PC/mac?  (Eg choose orientation or greyscale/color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard this is 10 times better than the default AirPrint functionality that comes with iOS. It also has tons more useful features. You might want to try the free trial, and see if it works for you!

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/